# Hide the button in the last row of the table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, user-interface

Here's my html

```
  <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered" style="width:100%" id="HeightConfig">
    <tbody id="HeightConfigBody">
@if (Model != null)
{
@foreach (var data in Model.Reverse())
{
     <tr>
                         <td style="width:40%">
  <label><b>Recorded Time:</b> <input type="text" id="recordDate"  class="recordDate"   
  value="@data.recordDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" disabled></label>
                      </td>



                       <td style="width:40%">
                         <label><b>Height (CM):</b> <input type="text" id="ColumnTypeData" class="ColumnTypeData" 
                          value="@data.ColumnTypeData" ></label>
                      </td>

                      <td style="width:40%">
                           <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="delete"
                            data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal" data-align="center">
                            <div id="minusHeight"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                            </a>


     <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="add"  >
                              <div id="addHeight" ><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
     </a>
                       </td>

</tr>

}
}

     </tbody>
  </table>
```

I need to hide the "plus button" in the third column, and display only in the last row.

this is what I got

```
<script>
 debugger;
        var x = document.getElementById("HeightConfig").rows.length;
        var ctr = 1
        $("#HeightConfig tbody tr").each(function (key, value) {
            debugger;

            if (ctr != x)
            {
                $(this).find('.addHeight').hide();

            }
            ctr++;
        });
</script>
```

i get first the length of the table, then loop on each row, then when the counter match the last row of the table it will not hide the button

Comment: You have multiple rows, but the rows contain elements with `id`s. **IDs must be unique on the page.** The markup is invalid. If you want to identify those divs, use a class, not an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addHeight is the **id** of the div and not the class name.
You can either make it the class name or use

```
 $(this).find('#addHeight').hide();
```

in the if condition of your code.

If you want to hide all the buttons simply make addheight the class name of the div and then use the following line:

```
$('.addHeight').hide();
```

Comment: how can I just HIDE ALL buttons?

Comment: Strongly recommend **not** encouraging the continued use of invalid HTML.

Comment: @rickyProgrammer: That wasn't your question.

Comment: @rickyProgrammer: No, you should fix the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

No need for all that (as you guessed). :-)

In modern browsers (basically anything except IE8 and earlier; [details](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)), you could do it with CSS via [`:not`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) with [`:last-of-type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo):

```css
#HeightConfig tr:not(:last-of-type) a[title=add] {
  display: none;
}
```

Example:

```css
#HeightConfig tr:not(:last-of-type) a[title=add] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered" style="width:100%" id="HeightConfig">
    <tbody id="HeightConfigBody">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Recorded Time:</b> <input type="text" id="recordDate"  class="recordDate"   
  value="@data.recordDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" disabled></label>
            </td>



            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Height (CM):</b> <input type="text" id="ColumnTypeData" class="ColumnTypeData" 
                          value="@data.ColumnTypeData" ></label>
            </td>

            <td style="width:40%">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="delete" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal" data-align="center">
                    <div id="minusHeight"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>


                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="add">
                    <div id="addHeight"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Recorded Time:</b> <input type="text" id="recordDate"  class="recordDate"   
  value="@data.recordDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" disabled></label>
            </td>



            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Height (CM):</b> <input type="text" id="ColumnTypeData" class="ColumnTypeData" 
                          value="@data.ColumnTypeData" ></label>
            </td>

            <td style="width:40%">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="delete" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal" data-align="center">
                    <div id="minusHeight"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>


                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="add">
                    <div id="addHeight"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Recorded Time:</b> <input type="text" id="recordDate"  class="recordDate"   
  value="@data.recordDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" disabled></label>
            </td>



            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Height (CM):</b> <input type="text" id="ColumnTypeData" class="ColumnTypeData" 
                          value="@data.ColumnTypeData" ></label>
            </td>

            <td style="width:40%">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="delete" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal" data-align="center">
                    <div id="minusHeight"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>


                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="add">
                    <div id="addHeight"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Recorded Time:</b> <input type="text" id="recordDate"  class="recordDate"   
  value="@data.recordDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" disabled></label>
            </td>



            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Height (CM):</b> <input type="text" id="ColumnTypeData" class="ColumnTypeData" 
                          value="@data.ColumnTypeData" ></label>
            </td>

            <td style="width:40%">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="delete" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal" data-align="center">
                    <div id="minusHeight"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>


                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="add">
                    <div id="addHeight"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, with jQuery, you can use [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and the jQuery-specific [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/):

```
$("#HeightConfig tr:not(:last) a[title=add]").hide();
```

Example:

```js
$("#HeightConfig tr:not(:last) a[title=add]").hide();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered" style="width:100%" id="HeightConfig">
    <tbody id="HeightConfigBody">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Recorded Time:</b> <input type="text" id="recordDate"  class="recordDate"   
  value="@data.recordDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" disabled></label>
            </td>



            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Height (CM):</b> <input type="text" id="ColumnTypeData" class="ColumnTypeData" 
                          value="@data.ColumnTypeData" ></label>
            </td>

            <td style="width:40%">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="delete" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal" data-align="center">
                    <div id="minusHeight"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>


                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="add">
                    <div id="addHeight"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Recorded Time:</b> <input type="text" id="recordDate"  class="recordDate"   
  value="@data.recordDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" disabled></label>
            </td>



            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Height (CM):</b> <input type="text" id="ColumnTypeData" class="ColumnTypeData" 
                          value="@data.ColumnTypeData" ></label>
            </td>

            <td style="width:40%">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="delete" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal" data-align="center">
                    <div id="minusHeight"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>


                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="add">
                    <div id="addHeight"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Recorded Time:</b> <input type="text" id="recordDate"  class="recordDate"   
  value="@data.recordDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" disabled></label>
            </td>



            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Height (CM):</b> <input type="text" id="ColumnTypeData" class="ColumnTypeData" 
                          value="@data.ColumnTypeData" ></label>
            </td>

            <td style="width:40%">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="delete" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal" data-align="center">
                    <div id="minusHeight"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>


                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="add">
                    <div id="addHeight"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Recorded Time:</b> <input type="text" id="recordDate"  class="recordDate"   
  value="@data.recordDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" disabled></label>
            </td>



            <td style="width:40%">
                <label><b>Height (CM):</b> <input type="text" id="ColumnTypeData" class="ColumnTypeData" 
                          value="@data.ColumnTypeData" ></label>
            </td>

            <td style="width:40%">
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="delete" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal" data-align="center">
                    <div id="minusHeight"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>


                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-default" title="add">
                    <div id="addHeight"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </a>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using simple ***CSS***

```
#HeightConfig tr a[title=add] {
  display: none;
}

#HeightConfig tr:last-child a[title=add] {
  display: block;
}
```

or using ***jQuery***

```
$("#HeightConfig tr a[title=add]").hide();
$("#HeightConfig tr:last-child a[title=add]").show();
```

As per your comment, If you want just hide all buttons you can simply put:

```
$("#HeightConfig tr a[title=add]").hide();
```

or in css

```
#HeightConfig tr a[title=add] {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Note that, as I note in my answer, the CSS version will not work in IE8 and earlier. (IE8 doesn't support either `:last-child` [your answer] or `:last-of-type` [mine, though I'm not sure why I used it rather than just `:last-child`]).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder,  I know that. ty for the heads up I missed to mention that in the answer.